# Custom Rails Method Not Updating Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom method to update a join table row that used to work and is for some reason errorlessly-failing.

The app is a basic course portal with `courses` and `lessons` joined by `lesson_completions`, which have `user_id`s, `lesson_id`s, and a boolean value for `complete`.

The link I'm using looks like this:

```
<% if @lesson_completion.complete %>
  <td class="pr-1"><%= link_to "<i class='far fa-check-square'></i>".html_safe, uncomplete_lesson_path(@lesson), method: :post, class: "text-red" %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Mark as Unfinished".html_safe, uncomplete_lesson_path(@lesson), method: :post, class: "text-red" %></td>
<% else %>
  <td class="pr-1"><%= link_to "<i class='far fa-square'></i>".html_safe, complete_lesson_path(@lesson), method: :post, class: "text-red" %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Mark Lesson as Completed".html_safe, complete_lesson_path(@lesson), method: :post, class: "text-red" %></td>
<% end %>
```

The methods are in my `lesson_completion_controller`:

```
 def complete_lesson
    @lesson_completion = LessonCompletion.find(params[:id])
    if @lesson_completion.update_attributes(complete: true)
        redirect_to course_module_path(CourseModule.find(Lesson.find(@lesson_completion.lesson_id).id))
        flash[:notice] = "Congratulations on completing that lesson!"
    else
        redirect_to lesson_path(Lesson.find(@lesson_completion.lesson_id))
        flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
  end

  def uncomplete_lesson
    @lesson_completion = LessonCompletion.find(params[:id])
    if @lesson_completion.update_attributes(complete: false)
        redirect_to lesson_path(Lesson.find(@lesson_completion.lesson_id))
        flash[:notice] = "Congratulations on completing that lesson!"
    else
        redirect_to lesson_path(Lesson.find(@lesson_completion.lesson_id))
        flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
  end
```

If I use a debugger and look at the value for `@lesson_completion` on that page it confirms the correct `user_id` and `lesson_id` values.

My routes look like this:

```
 post "lesson_completion/:id/complete_lesson" => "lesson_completion#complete_lesson", as: "complete_lesson"
  post "lesson_completion/:id/uncomplete_lesson" => "lesson_completion#uncomplete_lesson", as: "uncomplete_lesson"
```

When I click the button, the server log shows no errors:

```
Started POST "/lesson_completion/1/complete_lesson" for ::1 at 2020-09-17 15:17:37 -0700
Processing by LessonCompletionController#complete_lesson as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"HlCIdRVnOJZIHwPqWoJcu3XpNppi5LNSFvL4odU7DsR42Mw6Ld60IXJxzO/8yEw0qX/LH2PuWFuaywP4Ci3VRw==", "id"=>"1"}
  LessonCompletion Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "lesson_completions".* FROM "lesson_completions" WHERE "lesson_completions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:4
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:5
  Lesson Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "lessons".* FROM "lessons" WHERE "lessons"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:5
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:5
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:5
  CACHE Lesson Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "lessons".* FROM "lessons" WHERE "lessons"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:6
  CourseModule Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "course_modules".* FROM "course_modules" WHERE "course_modules"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lesson_completion_controller.rb:6
Redirected to http://localhost:5000/course_modules/1
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

Can anyone see why this value isn't updating?  It used to work and is driving me absolutely bonkers now!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `update_attributes` instead of `update`? What version of rails are you on? Also, do you have the option of changing up your models a bit?

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessible :complete` on the `LessonCompletion` model?

Comment: Although there are many things you can improve in this piece of code, to see why the value is not updating you can force `update_attributes` to raise an exception by appending a bang (!) sign to it `@lesson_completion.update_attributes!(complete: false)`. Exccpetion will have the reason you are looking for.

Comment: @SajjadUmar I tried this and it still goes through as if it's working.  No errors, just not updating!

Comment: @Ashley These methods are in the `lesson_completion` controller, which has `:complete` as a permitted param.

Comment: @jvillian I'm on rails 5.2 but I learned on 4 something and possibly haven't updated my personal syntax accordingly?

Comment: There was no log of running update SQL. I will 1. check the validation of the models. 2. run rails console and manually run the code 3. use byebug gem and byebug before the update_attributes